# Perl regex in a variable string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm new to perl with regex.

I'm trying to have a string of oid 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.*.192.168.1.1, but I'm not sure how to do it.
I tried the below, but it is getting error which is saying not able to recognize the oid.

```
my $matchanyoid = "/(\d+)$/";
my $dot1dTpFdbAddress = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.',$matchanyoid,'\.',$srcip;
```

Answer (score 1):

Comma is not a concatenation operator, dot is:

```
my $dot1dTpFdbAddress = '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.' . $matchanyoid . '\.' . $srcip;
```

If you are trying to build a regular expression, note that the first several dots are not backslashed, so they can match anything. To avoid lots of backslashes, you can use the `\Q ... \E` construct:

```
my $matchanyoid = '(\d+)';
my $srcip = 12;
my $regex = qr/\Q1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.\E$matchanyoid\.$srcip/;
print '1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2.123.12' =~ $regex;
```

Comment: I got the error: ERROR: The base OBJECT IDENTIFIER "(?^:1\.3\.6\.1\.2\.1\.4\.22\.1\.2\.\/\(d\+\)\\.192\.1168\.1\.32)" is expected in dotted decimal notation.

Comment: @kyusan93: Then you are probably not telling us all the important details. I updated the answer, it works for me.

Comment: I'm trying to use Net::SNMP to get the mac address via oid, but I only know the ip address and the 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2, but between the 1.3.6.1.2.1.4.22.1.2 and the IP, there is some other * numbers and I do not how to use the perl regex to do the *.